# JPA how to compare input login field with the md5 stored in the database

Tags: java, jpa

Need help with comparing text with md5 from database, how do i go by doing this ;S So i added a bit more code, but it still doesn't wasn't to work, the "Invalid Username/Password." label comes up, im confused lol, please help :D

```
    User user = em.find(User.class, (int) 1);
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(user.get(0).getStrUserPassword().getBytes());
    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

            if (txtUsername.getText().equals(user.get(0).getStrUserName())
                    && txtPassword.getText().equals(sb.toString())) {
                this.dispose();
                SubMenu sm = new SubMenu();
                sm.setVisible(true);
            } else if (txtUsername.getText().trim().length() == 0) {
                lblErrorMessage.setText("Input Username.");
                txtUsername.requestFocus();
            } else if (txtPassword.getText().trim().length() == 0) {
                lblErrorMessage.setText("Input Password.");
                txtPassword.requestFocus();
            } else {
                lblErrorMessage.setText("Invalid Username/Password.");
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly is the problem you are facing?  Is there an error thrown?

Comment: How are you converting to md5 to store in the DB? Just use the same process on the password entered by the user and compare that with the DB value. Also, I wouldn't load all users, you should have a named query to get user by username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match the password input with the md5 of password you have in database, you need to first convert the input password to MD5, and then compare it with what you have in database.

I suppose you already know how to convert a string to MD5, since you already did it when you stored the password in the database.  Anyway, here it is :

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(password.getBytes());
byte byteData[] = md.digest();
```

Also, you don't need to retrieve all users from database, just get the one which matches the username.

Answer (score 1):

You should not retrieve all the users as you know that there will be one user corresponding to the username. You can rather use em.find(User.class,userName);

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(text.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
                sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));


    if(txtPassword.getText().equals(sb.toString()))  //the comparison should take place like this
```

Comment: I have edited the code up top, could someone have a look and please help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem